# JMeter Assertion : Error when comparing variables

Tags: groovy, jmeter, compare, jmeter-5.0

I am trying to assert my API response data with a value I obtained from my Database.

My code fails to compare my variables unless I add `toString()` to both my variable. Is there any way around it or is `toString()` mandatory?

The code in question is :

```
Boolean comparision = false;
for (int i; i < vars.getObject("dbData").size(); i++) {    
if (vars.getObject("dbData").get(i).get("DbData").toString().equals(${codeid_API}.toString()))
{
    comparision = true;            
}     
}
```

`${codeid_API}` is the variable where I stored my API response data.
`(vars.getObject("dbData").get(i).get("DbData")` gets the value from my DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  [Objects.equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)) instead

```
Objects.equals(vars.getObject("dbData").get(i).get("DbData"), ${codeid_API});
```

> Returns true if the arguments are equal to each other and false otherwise.

For integer you can compare using `==` and use `as int` for casting

```
if (vars.getObject("dbData").get(i).get("DbData") as int == vars.get("codeid_API") as int );
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the Response. Still the assertion results false until I add `toString()` to both variables. To give more info, both data from DB and API Response is an integer

Answer (score 1):

Don't inline JMeter variables in form of `${codeid_API}` into Groovy scripts, in case of enabled compiled scripts caching it will be resolved **only once** and it might break your script logic.

Consider replacing it with `vars.get('codeid_API`) instead where `vars` is the shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance

Quote from [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) documentation:

> JMeter processes function and variable references before passing the script field to the interpreter, so the references will only be resolved once. Variable and function references in script files will be passed verbatim to the interpreter, which is likely to cause a syntax error. In order to use runtime variables, please use the appropriate props methods, e.g.
>
> ```
> props.get("START.HMS");
>
> props.put("PROP1","1234");
> ```

More information: [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter)